# Is it possible to change the default thread stacksize for a dll not under your control c++ win32

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have an application which uses a lot of threads. Most of these threads are created by third party dlls which I have no control over.

In order to reduce virtual memory usage I set the default stack size to 0.5MiB (instead of the default 1MiB) for the executable. This reduces address space usage by over 500 MiB, which is very usefull, as XP (unfortunately) has a virtual memory limit of 2GiB.

I have had to recently integrate another third party dll into the application which causes a stack overflow at this level, thus I have to set the default stack size back up to 1MiB.

The DLL is creating a separate thread which is the one that causes the problem, so I cannot control it by specifying a thread size on the thread that uses the DLL within my application using CreateThread options.

So my question is is there anyway to get the DLL to have a different default stacksize for internal threads than the executable, given I cannot edit the code of that Dll

Comment: What are you actually trying to fix? The if you are running low on memory, the parts of stack that isn't used shouldn't matter, since it's allocated on a "demand basis" - and even if it isn't for some reason, it should be fine to swap out and never be used again. 

Without knowing which third party libraries, I'd say you're asking for a solution that can't be found.

Comment: Yeah, I know its allocated on demand, but it does use up virtual memory space, which (on XP unfortunately) kills the application at 2GiB. It is an application which is memory heavy. I know that this may be one of those unfortunate unfixable issues, but it is worth asking just in case.

Comment: There are not a wholeheckofalot of reasonable things you can do with a process that runs a *thousand* threads.  That's just unreasonable.  Specify a 64-bit OS, link with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE and you'll double the VM size.  Go looking for another job next.

Comment: @Hans Sometimes you cannot force a company that is using your software to upgrade to another OS, they pay the bills. If every time you face a hard problem, quitting your job cannot be the answer. It is attitudes like that which cause code that looks like the application I am working on. If it turns out that this is problem that cannot be fixed, it just means that I can up the estimates, and the cost of implementation goes up (and therefore we can repay some technical debt and the code quality goes up). I need to examine all available options and trade-offs so we can make an informed decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need to use [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) or other PE hooking code to redirect the DLL's import of `CreateThread()` to your own implementation stub that trampoline's into the original imported function using a different value for the `dwStackSize` parameter.  That way, your main app's threads can use 0.5MB and the DLL's threads can use 1.0MB.

Comment: What if the DLL's threads sometimes need all that space? There is no easy answer for this other than: work with the vendor of that DLL on a solution, or else find a replacement.  Hacking it somehow is worth a shot, though.

Comment: This is the only thing I could think of that would be possible, however it seems to me that it would be a definite final option.   
@Kaz I am already talking to the vendor, but I wanted to know if there was another solution that could be used if the updates don't happen.  as noted in another comment above, it is unreasonable of our application to use 1000 threads, but that is the way of the world.